# Live Chat support in my website

Tags: chat, livechat

I just wanted to know if there is any (preferently freeware) solution to provide live chat support in my website, but connected to a Live Messenger account, because I would like to answer by this way.

Comment: Please people, don't use this question to promote your chat app if that not provides the functionality asked in the question, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [eBuddy embed](http://www.ebuddy.com/in_your_website.php). They provide widget to be embed in your webpage to chat with you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's any easy way to do this with Live Messenger.

If you can use Yahoo! Messenger instead of Live Messenger, they provide a nice easy free widget which does what you want, called [Yahoo! Messenger Pingbox](http://messenger.yahoo.com/pingbox).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.Net and OK with using Silverlight, you can look into this flexible [option](http://dotnetkicks.com/silverlight/A_SilverLight_WCF_Chat). It is a Polling duplex solution easy to implement. For PHP [Chantlive](http://www.chantlive.com/) is an option.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'll try Windows Live Messenger Web Toolkit to develop my white-labeled solution, but thanks to all of you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at olark (olark.com). Super easy to embed on the page, and it works with most chat clients, so you don't have to use new software.